# Call a program through ssh -X but dont display anything

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding

I have to run this program I need to launch through ssh that absolutely needs a gui to run but I have no use for the visual output (it wont launch if I start it from an ssh session, I need to start it from an ssh -X session). Its actually quite annoying to have the windows open and steal focus from what I'm working on so I am looking for a way to run an ssh -X session but to get rid of the visual output it would normally produce.

Comment: Have you tried pointing the program at a headless X server on the remote?

Comment: I dont have admin privileges and xvfb is not available, is there another way to set a headless X server?